# Avoiding nested conditions

Tags: python, python-3.x, algorithm

I am designing a program in which I'm trying to avoid nesting conditional statements.

Basically, I have 2 sets of 3 parameters : `a_changes`, `b_changes` and `c_changes` are bools,
and they are associated with `a`, `b` and `c`, that are lists if they change or floats if they don't.
My aim is to transform non-changing parameters into lists of the same length as changing parameters.

An example would be :

```
a_changes = True
b_changes = False
c_changes = False
a = [0.21, 0.25, 0.29]
b = 0.13
c = 0.78
```

becomes

```
a_changes = True
b_changes = False
c_changes = False
a = [0.21, 0.25, 0.29]
b = [0.13, 0.13, 0.13]
c = [0.78, 0.78, 0.78]
```

Problem is : multiple parameters can change at the same time, so you could have :

```
a_changes = True
b_changes = True
c_changes = False
a = [0.21, 0.25, 0.29]
b = [0.13, 0.13, 0.13]
c = 0.78
```

becomes

```
a_changes = True
b_changes = True
c_changes = False
a = [0.21, 0.25, 0.29]
b = [0.13, 0.13, 0.13]
c = [0.78, 0.78, 0.78]
```

If multiple parameters change, their length is the same, so no problem coming from there. However, I would want to avoid having a multitude of nested conditional statements. Is it at all possible? Is there a Data Structure I could use?

Comment: When a variable changes from a `float` into a `list`, how long should the `list` be?

Comment: @quamrana the list should be as long as the other changing parameters' lists

Comment: I don't see why you would need nested conditionals for this; it should be flat. What did you already try? Maybe you want to use a 2D [NumPy array](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/arrays.ndarray.html#arrays-ndarray)?

Comment: What should happen when all of a,b,c are floats and one or more needs to be a list?

Comment: @quamrana all parameters cannot be floats, at least one must be a list

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work if at least one input is a list:

```
def refine_arguments(a, b, c, a_changes, b_changes, c_changes):

    # get the max len of one of the list (should be all the same listlenght)      
    maxlen = max(len(i) for i in (a, b, c) if isinstance(i, list))

    # if the X_changes is true use the float value times maxlen, else leave as is
    a = [a] * maxlen if not a_changes and not isinstance(a, list) else a
    b = [b] * maxlen if not b_changes and not isinstance(b, list) else b
    c = [c] * maxlen if not c_changes and not isinstance(c, list) else c

    return a, b, c


a_changes = True
b_changes = True
c_changes = False
a = [0.21, 0.25, 0.29]
b = [0.13, 0.13, 0.13]
c = 0.78

print(*refine_arguments(a, b, c, a_changes, b_changes, c_changes))

a_changes = True
b_changes = False
c_changes = False
a = [0.21, 0.25, 0.29]
b = 0.78
c = 0.78

print(*refine_arguments(a, b, c, a_changes, b_changes, c_changes))
```

Output:

```
[0.21, 0.25, 0.29] [0.13, 0.13, 0.13] [0.78, 0.78, 0.78]
[0.21, 0.25, 0.29] [0.78, 0.78, 0.78] [0.78, 0.78, 0.78]
```

Use `a,b,c = refine_arguments(a, b, c, a_changes, b_changes, c_changes)` to work with a,b,c later on.

Comment: Thanks, could not wrap my head around a flat version, this works fine for me :)

Comment: @olir edited to be a function for ease of use.   `a,b,c = refine_arguments(a, b, c, a_changes, b_changes, c_changes)` should do the trick

Answer (score 1):

The data structure you may want to use are numpy arrays. If you have a lot of parameters, use a dictionary to allow loop operations:

```
my_data = {}

my_data["a"] = [0.21, 0.25, 0.29]
my_data["b"] = 0.13
my_data["c"] = 0.78

length = 1

for param in my_data:
    my_data[param] = np.array(my_data[param], ndmin=1) # at least 1d
    length = max(length, len(my_data[param]))

for param in my_data:
    my_data[param] = np.ones(length) * my_data[param] # make sure all is the same lentgh
```

Comment: In fact, most of the time it is not needed to force the arrays to have the same shape. scalars (arrays with shape (1,)) are automatically processed on each element of longer arrays

Answer (score 1):

You have a lot of redundant information it seems. The processing really only depends on whether something is a list: booleans are not necessary. Also, you don't need separate variables, since it's easier to work with batches of things when they are in a sequence.

Store your data in a list:

```
data = [a, b, c]
```

Get the length of a list:

```
size = next((len(x) for x in data if isinstance(x, list)), 1)
```

Notice that this call to `next` guards against all the elements being `float` by returning one. Now do the transform:

```
for i in range(len(data)):
    if ~isinstance(data[i], list):
        data[i] = [data[i]] * size
```

Or more concisely:

```
data = [x if isinstance(x, list) else [x] * size for x in data]
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer. I originally created the booleans as I've always been told to limit the use of isinstance-type functions. However, I see your point. I do have to keep the parameters separate though, as they come from an JSON input file, and it might confuse the user.

Comment: @olirwin. How you do your processing should be a black box to the user. If you need to have separate variables, do `a, b, c = data` at the end. If you just return the variables in a function, python would wrap it in a tuple anyway. If you return a list instead, users wouldn't notice.